# pygame.Surface object is not callable

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        state = 2
        mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        leave(mouseX, mouseY)
```

When I press the "x" in the top left gives me an error that reads:

```
leave(mouseX, mouseY)

TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable
```

Comment: can you tell what "leave(mouseX, mouseY)" do?

Comment: if `leave` is `Surface` then you can't use it as function with `leave()`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure without seeing a little bit more of the code but my best guess is that you have named a `surface` object leave and it is conflicting with the function that you have also named leave. Try changing the name of one of them to something else.